# How can I use the value of a variable as constant?

Tags: php, variables, constants

1. I have a PHP site which uses language system based on "define" method.
   For example:

   ```
   define("_question_1", "How old are you?");
   define("_question_2", "Question 2?");
   define("_question_3", "Question 3?");
   ....
   define("_question_10", "Question 10?");
   ```
2. I have 5-10 questions I need to ask. And I need to select what question I want to ask. So I make a query to my DB. Something like:

   ```
   SELECT q_title FROM questions_db WHERE id=3 OR id=10;
   ```

   Database returns two TEXT(!) values:

   ```
   _question_3, _question_10
   ```

   Which I save to:

   ```
   $a = _question_3; 
   $b = _question_10;
   ```
3. Next thing I need is to show the text of the description defined earlier. When I use _question_3 as VARIABLE it works like this:

   ```
   echo ""._question_3.""; //returns "Question 3?"
   ```

   But I have only _question_3 as TEXT value and it's works like this:

   ```
   echo "".$a.""; //returns "_question_3"
   ```

THE QUESTION: How to convert text value to PHP variable and make something like?

```
    define("_question_3", "Question 3?");
    $a = _question_3; //text value
    //do something with $a.... 
    echo "".$a.""; //returns "Question 3?"
```

Thanks for help.
P.S. Please change the title if it doesn't clear to understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`constant()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) to use your variable value as constant, e.g.

```
echo constant($a);
```

Comment: Amazingly! Works! That's what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

1. In PHP you could use variable variable – dynamic variable names.

   ```
   $a = '_question_3'; 
   $b = 'Question 3?';

   $$a = $b;
   echo $b;
   // prints "Question 3?"
   echo $_question_3;
   // prints "Question 3?"
   ```

But it's not good solution. Try not to use dynamic variable names.

2. May be associative array will be more suitable to you?

   ```
   $questions = []; // Creating an empty array
   $questions['_question_3']['question'] = 'Question 3?'; // Storing a question
   $questions['_question_3']['answers'] = [ // Adding answers
       'Answer 1',
       'Answer 2',
       'Answer 3'
   ];
   ```
3. Or declare a `Question` class and create instances of it.

   ```
   class Question
   {
     public $Question;

     public $Answers;

     __construct($question, $answers)
     {
        $this->Question = $question;
        $this->Answers = $answers;
     }
   }

   $q1 = new Question('Question 1?', ['Answer 1', 'Answer 2', 'Answer 3']);
   ```

Comment: Second way doesn't work for me because I want have a possibility to store  questions in Database and edit them in admin-panel.

Comment: What reason is preventing you to do that?

Comment: Due to the first way – how will I know what value save to $b?

Comment: The answer above is answered what I needed! Thanks for the help too – I will think for the future about using associative arrays in similar cases.

Comment: Ok, it's good that you have your question answered. But you're doing wrong. Constants are not designed for that. You'd better find more suitable and proper ways to implement your algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Try constant() it returns the value of a constant, for example:

```
var_dump(constant('YourConstantNameHere'));
```

or with variables

```
var_dump(constant($a));
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php