# How can I use a variable to get the value from a constant?

Tags: php, constants

I am writing an installer which I am passing the constant names as an array of strings to check if they exist, but inside the loop, i would also like to check if the values meet the requirements for what that defined constant is for.

```
<?php

$defines(
    'FOO'=>Array('type'=>'int', 'min'=>0, 'max'=>100),
    'BAR'=>Array('type'=>'bool'),
    'ROO'=>Array('type'=>'path', 'write'=>true)
);

$errors = Array();
foreach($defines as $key=>$value) {
    if(!defined($key)) {
        $errors[] = $key . ' is not defined.';
    } else {
        $v = // how do i set this to the value defined for the define found.
    }
}
```

Related to the same scenario, using the array item `FOO` from `$defines`, is the following possible:

```
$v = ($value['type']) ...
```

... where `...` above is the method used to access the defined constant based on the `$key` value (which holds the constants name for the `defined` check)

I am using **PHP 5.6** .

Comment: The first part of my question is solved thanks to [this brief answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32025623/3504007) and following up with the live php documentation on the [constant()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) method.  Just need some info on the second part now.

Comment: You're welcome with the first part of your question :)

Comment: 1) So you want to check if the constants meet your requirements defined in the array? If yes what possible requirements do you have? 2) And if the constant is defined and the requirements are met you want to set `$v` to that value right? If yes you know that you would overwrite `$v` each time you enter the else statement?

Comment: @Rizier123 - correct.  `$v` is only a temp variable, but I also would like to know if something like the second part is possible. Now that I know the `constant()` command, it would look like  `$v = ($value['type'])constant($key);`    (heh, looks pretty funky  XD )

Comment: Yes, something like this is possible. But what are all possible requirements? `type`, `write`, `min`, `max`, ...? Also I still fail to see what exactly you want to do here with this code.

Comment: in the full project, the logic is more complex.  I do a switch on the type value and expect certain params based on those.  The additional possibles vary, but are specific to type, and I check for their existance.  This is really for a quick installer to check and report back reasonable information about what is missing, and what is allowed.

Comment: Not sure if I can follow you, but if now the problem is about the type requirement you probably look for `gettype()` / `settype()` depending if you want to set the type to that or check it against it.

Comment: @Rizier123 - since i am in the switch case, i can set it explicitly, I was more curious whether something like  `$type = 'int'; $value = '1234'; $v = ($type)$value;` was possible

Comment: Then you probably look for `settype()`